# Team Foundation Server file check-in problem

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm storing SQL database backup file (*.bak) in the Visual Studio solution and checking it to TFS. However when I update this bacup file locally (backing up new database structure) it's not marked as "changed" in the solution explorer and not uploaded to TFS. 
How can I solve this problem and force VS to automatically check-in changed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SVN bridge.

SvnBridge allows you to use TortoiseSVN and other Subversion clients with Team Foundation Server. It converts the calls made by your Subversion client to the API supported by TFS.

SvnBridge acts as a bridge between TortoiseSVN and TFS. You point SvnBridge at the TFS server, and point TortoiseSVN at SvnBridge. This allows you to use TortoiseSVN with any TFS server without needing to change the TFS server in any way (no need to convince your TFS system administrator of anything!).

There is two versions of SVNBridge: "SVNbridge client" and "SVNbridge server". The names are slightly misleading, as both of them run on your desktop computer, and you never need to install anything on the Team Foundation Server computer. Most developers will just run the "SVNbridge client" version, which sits in your system tray. However, if you have multiple SVN developers, you can let them all dial into your computer using the "SVNbridge server" version, and in effect your computer becomes a SVN server which in turn talks to Team Foundation Server.

Download it here: http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. SVNBridge is awesome and now I can work with my favorite SVN!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually check out the file, or write a script that runs as part of your backup routine to check out the file.

Comment: Okay, normally when we check code into the server, we go into VS and select "Check in Pending Changes". How would we add a script that is triggered when we do this? I think that there is a deeper problem, as this problem is also appearing on all of the source code for our InstallAware files, with extensions *.mia, *.bak, *.miaf, *.drm, etc.

Comment: This looks strange as for me. What if I have hundrens of additional files (now I have tens of such files) 
For example SVN (my favorite version control) compares file modification date and file contents and then marks file as "modified". This is done automatically.

I have a hope TFS has similar functionality and I just did not turned it on. Maybe there is a hidden switch somewhere.

Comment: Currently released versions of TFS do not support this kind of functionality. I'm sorry but any organization that currently uses TFS has been duped and screwed ower.

Comment: In TFS you have to check out a file before you can check it in.  I don't my version control to check in anything that has changed without it being formally checked out beforehand...

Comment: @Gravitas - install the power tools and run 'tfpt online /?' to see the complete list of options for automating this process.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the extension of the file to something other than ".bak". Visual Studio may ignore any files of type ".bak" as these are usually backup files which should not be checked into the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have plenty of other files (not BAK) which are rarely changed, but they are also not committed when modified.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you're both logged in as Administrator, it causes synchronization problems? Try creating a separate account for all users in the system. This setup would be closer to the original environment that Microsoft tested the software in.

Comment: Than you for your answer. This may be an issue since we're working under same account, but this could not affect on file versions cheking for non text files like database backup, becuse this is checked locally (not on the server)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [power tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx)
2. For easy checkout/checkin from Windows Explorer, make sure you select the appropriate option in the installer (it's unchecked by default).
3. For easy scripting -- or if you're just a command line kind of guy like me -- run 'tfpt online /?' and review the available options.  The tool can automatically pend edits based on file attributes or MD5 hashes.  You also have the option to diff the tree structure for added or deleted files.  (No support for autodetecting renames; pend them manually).

As another poster mentioned, you can use SvnBridge instead of #2.  Their integration with Explorer (eg Tortoise) is probably more robust at the moment than the MS shell extension, which is in its very first release.  However, it's no substitute for the rest of the power tools, which I think any power user will find invaluable.